# Strapi query all the objects that contain a certain element in the array of objects

Tags: mongoose, strapi

I have collection from which I want to fetch all the entries that have a certain user id in the participants array of object.

Sample json

Note: Participant is a component

```
{
        "Participants": [
            {
                "_id": "5f1c128ab39be54110617151",
                "createdAt": "2020-07-25T11:07:54.847Z",
                "updatedAt": "2020-07-25T12:00:38.584Z",
                "__v": 0,
                "user": {
                    "confirmed": true,
                    "blocked": false,
                    "_id": "5f105109ec6b031be0dd9b3b",
                    "username": "pendu",
                    "password": "$2a$10$WNEWKWRXVouKZfNO9Rh.P.lzJbQX7YQH7Qlq131Af7A5iLi.TzMuq",
                    "email": "pendu@gmail.com",
                    "provider": "local",
                    "createdAt": "2020-07-16T13:07:21.705Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-07-23T14:08:06.587Z",
                    "__v": 0,
                    "role": "5f100c45e8ca8a3bfc878094",
                    "profile": "5f198d25a6786538b8f1ac19",
                    "id": "5f105109ec6b031be0dd9b3b"
                },
                "id": "5f1c128ab39be54110617151"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5f1c128ab39be54110617152",
                "createdAt": "2020-07-25T11:07:54.847Z",
                "updatedAt": "2020-07-25T12:00:38.586Z",
                "__v": 0,
                "user": {
                    "confirmed": true,
                    "blocked": false,
                    "_id": "5f189608b857d417d864237a",
                    "username": "izhan",
                    "email": "izhan@gmail.com",
                    "password": "$2a$10$oA784bd/OIKYR0f59clZx.slL9p0kPGguulHN/StSJwyXMz3VzavO",
                    "provider": "local",
                    "createdAt": "2020-07-22T19:39:52.245Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-07-23T14:09:49.309Z",
                    "__v": 0,
                    "profile": "5f1999b1022bcf40fc27c8a5",
                    "role": "5f100c45e8ca8a3bfc878094",
                    "id": "5f189608b857d417d864237a"
                },
                "id": "5f1c128ab39be54110617152"
            }
        ],
        "createdAt": "2020-07-25T11:07:54.774Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-07-25T12:00:38.627Z",
        "__v": 2,
        "user_1": "5f189608b857d417d864237a",
        "user_2": "5f105109ec6b031be0dd9b3b",
        "id": "5f1c128ab39be5411061714e"
    }
]
```

As you can see that the user exist in an array and they all have their respective ids.

My attempt to fetch data

```
await strapi.query('messages').model.find({"Participants.user.id":id}) // []
await strapi.query('messages').model.find({"Participants":{$elemMatch:{"user.id":id}}}) //[]
```

Comment: What is the result of your attempt? Are you getting an error or an unexpected result?

Comment: I'm getting an empty array